# Internet Explorer generates extra br

Tags: html, internet-explorer, rendering-engine

I have an issue where Internet Explorer is generating an additional `br` element that is not in my source. The additional `br` effects the page's layout and is visible when using the developer tool. I've tried removing all hard returns between the surrounding elements but the additional `br` persists. Firefox and Chrome do not have this issue. Ideas on what I can do to fix the issue?

Instead of

```
First line.
Second line.
```

I get

```
First line

Second line.
```

Code Example

```
    <asp:ImageButton ID="RemoveItem" AlternateText="Remove Item" 
        ImageUrl="~/img/buttons/remove.png" runat="server" CssClass="remove"
        CommandName="Remove" OnCommand="RemoveCartItem_Command" />
    <br runat="server" id="TotalBreak" />
    <span class="fieldlabel">Total</span>
```

And what I end up with (... used to show I've shortened rendered ids)

```
<input id="...RemoveItem" class="remove" alt="Remove Item"
       src="img/buttons/remove.png" type=image name="...RemoveItem" />
<br id="...TotalBreak"/>
<br/>
<span class="fieldlabel">Total</span>
```

Comment: Can you post sample code that produces the extra break and / or a link to a page demonstrating the issue?

Comment: code? 10 character requirement

Comment: @ryanprayogo unfortunately this is IE8 have yet to test in IE6/7

Comment: @ahsteele: it was meant to be a joke since, well, IE6 does very weird things :)

Comment: @ryanprayogo hehehe, I think the trident rendering engine does very weird things regardless of browser version ;)

Comment: `runat="server"` for a `<br>`? Have you done a View Source from any other browser, besides IE8?

Comment: @Stephen At times this code removes the `br` server side (not my code). The extra `br` is not visible in the source in any browser not even IE. It's evident on the screen by the visible extra line break and shows up when using the IE developer tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably due to `line-height` or another default in the browser's default style sheet. Like buyckbova said, you should use a CSS reset. Try Eric Meyer's, it's thorough: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Comment: I am using Meyer's CSS Reset but am still seeing the issue. :( I could be overriding `line-height` or another setting somewhere.

Comment: I haven't figured out which CSS property I am overwriting but turning off all CSS removes the extra `br` so I am sure that you are right. Now to find the offender.

Comment: If you put in Firebug Lite, you can see the trace of all styles for the element, which should help.

Answer (score 1):

Try a CSS reset to remove browser defaults.